# 'program' macro not correctly loading

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, anchor-solana

I'm facing issues in compiling my Rust program, where I'm getting errors pointing to the *program* macro when I run *anchor test*. What could be causing this issue? I tried running *cargo check* but got the same result.

**lib.rs**

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod mycalculatorapp {
    use super::*;
pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>, init_message: String ) -> Result<()> {

    let calculator = &mut ctx.accounts.calculator;
    calculator.greeting = init_message;
    Ok(())
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    // #[account(init, payer=user, space=264)]
    // pub calculator: Account<'info, Calculator>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub systems_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[account]
pub struct Calculator {
    pub greeting: String,
    pub result: i64,
    pub remainder: i64  
}
```

Errors:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate`
 --> programs/mycalculatorapp/src/lib.rs:5:1
 |
 | #[program]
 | ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `__client_accounts_create` in the crate root
 |

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `try_accounts` found for struct `Create` in the current scope
  --> programs/mycalculatorapp/src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
  | #[program]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Create<'_>`
...
  | pub struct Create<'info> {
  | ------------------------ function or associated item `try_accounts` not found for this
  
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `try_accounts`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `anchor_lang::Accounts`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: could you post your code too? it looks like it is missing the `use` imports from within the program.

Comment: It looks like some issue in the the code and that's why anchor shows such error to `#[program]` span. Please share the complete program

Comment: @Netwave I've added some important parts of the code in the question. Please check

Comment: @Arjun [Here](https://github.com/devd-99/calculatordapp/blob/master/programs/mycalculatorapp/src/lib.rs) is the github link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be changed to

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod mycalculatorapp {
    use super::*;
pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>, init_message: String ) -> Result<()> {

    let calculator = &mut ctx.accounts.calculator;
    calculator.greeting = init_message;
    Ok(())
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer=user, space=264)]
    pub calculator: Account<'info, Calculator>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[account]
pub struct Calculator {
    pub greeting: String,
    pub result: i64,
    pub remainder: i64  
}
```

It was messed up due to the type instead of `systems_program` you needed `system_program`

also raise a PR over github. https://github.com/devd-99/calculatordapp/pulls/1

feel free to merge and checkout.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. Merged the PR.